# Is there a better alternative than SendKeys to change the focus in the WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

At the moment I have this to change focus of an element:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
```

Instead of using that I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("id").InvokeMember("click")
```

But to get focus to the next element in line, like the next one from the current focused item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in your question is hard to decode.  But if you mean, "can I use InvokeMember to change the focus" instead of using SendKeys, then yes.  Use InvokeMember("focus").  If you do it right then you don't need SendKeys at all anymore.  Which means that you don't need "focus" either.

Most of the important methods and properties of a element in the DOM are documented in the MSDN library docs for IHTMLElement and IHTMLElement2.  Several of them (but not all, like "click") are wrapped by the Winforms HtmlElement class, including the Focus() method.  The HtmlDocument.ActiveElement property provides a reference to the element that currently has the focus.

Comment: The element im trying to change with the class or the ID, and i know i had it right.

so i thought of getting it focused first, and then finding what element is focused, then that will give me the ID.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to explain something, but my gast is flabbered.  HtmlDocument.ActiveElement gives you the currently focused element.